After installing Ubuntu screen is big and blurry
I recently switch from Windows to Ubuntu. Now the PC screen is big and blurry. How can I fix it? The graphics card is a Nvidia GeForce GT 220.
Why doesn't it show any drivers when I run sudo ubuntu-drivers list command?

We're somewhat limited in what help we can provide; we've not yet been told what Ubuntu product, and what release you're using; thus don't know what options exist for you.

"nvidia gt 220 vt" is 14 years old, give or take.

Ubuntu versiion 24.04 LTS

Please add additional details to your question (via EDIT).... Also be clear with details; is this Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server??  Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop ??   ie. 24.04 is the release, but which 24.04 product?  FYI:  If this is a really old video card as @mikewhatever suggests, using a lighter flavor like Xubuntu maybe an option...  I switched out an Nvidia GPU on a QA box somewhat recently due to time being wasted on graphics issues, when the box was intended for install testing.. Issues appear first with GNOME, then KDE Plasma... with LXQt (Lubuntu) & Xfce (Xubuntu) usually last with GPU probs

Give Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu a try. The regular Ubuntu desktop may be too much for this old graphics card.

Also, open Additional Drivers in Software Sources. Does it list any additional driver?

I had a graphics issue on update to 24.04; I'm using amdgpu driver though - for me I needed to change grub to not use "splash"; you can do this temporarily at the grub prompt. Might be worth trying. It was somehow preventing the graphics driver from loading. Does it work from a live usb? Does lspci -v | grep -i -e nvidia -e nouveau give any info about your card? Does xrandr give you a list of graphics options?
